# Using resolve return as state parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am writing an SPA application using AngularJS and UI-Router. What I am trying to achieve is to use the result of the `resolve` method in the landing controller as state parameter for the same state.

This is what I am trying to do:

- The user logs in
- User lands on the `account` state,
- The stateParam `:accountId` is automatically populated with the value returned from the resolve method, for example the url becomes '/account/12334/' depending on the user.
- Any subsequent status is a 'child' of the account status.

This is what I tried:

```
  .state('account', {
    url: '/account/:accountId',
    templateUrl: '/partials/account.html',
    controller: 'AccountCtrl',
    resolve: {
      'accountId': ['Account', '$stateParams', function(Account, $stateParams) {
        $stateParams.accountId = Account.promise;
      }]
    }
  })
```

but the URL stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem myself: when I posted the question here on StackOverflow I simplified the problem, and I figured out that the problem wasn't in the the resolve method but in the way I was using the factory, getting an empty accountId.